# Ошибка с ключами

Tags: reactjs

Имеется такой код:

```js
function ElementList(props) {
    let names = props.names;
    let listItems = names.map((name) =>
        <Element key={name.name} />
    );
    return (
        {listItems}
    );
}

let names = [
    {id: 0, name: 'name1'},
    {id: 1, name: 'name2'},
    {id: 2, name: 'name3'},
];

class Show extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ElementList names={names}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Получаю ошибку: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {listItems}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
Искренне не пойму, что оно от меня хочет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался сам, нужно было перенести выражение listItems в return:

```
function ElementList(props) {
    let names = props.names;
    return (
        names.map((name) =>
            <Element key={name}/>
    ));
}
```

Comment: так выложи правильный код (или часть кода)! иначе этот "ответ" удалят как не содержащий решения

Comment: @nörbörnën извиняюсь, поправил, в местной этике пока не силен.

Comment: тут есть свой кодекс, вот - [часть, касающаяся ответов на вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/answering). но важно помнить вот что: so - сайт вопросов про программирование и ответов на эти вопросы. если ты опубликовал ответ то ответ должен быть _полезным_ тому кто задал вопрос и тому, кто в будущем обратится к этому вопросу

Comment: p.s. чот мне помнится, что в реакте можно объявить коллекцию элементов ровно таким образом как ты пробовал в коде вопроса. видимо, ты что-то не дожал. вечером посмотрю

Comment: @nörbörnën я так понял, мой способ работает с функцией, но не с классом, ибо другого объяснения я пока не нахожу.

Comment: нет! уверен, что там нехватало корневого элемента, что-то типа `return (<>{listItems}</>)` https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/jrXYRR?editors=0011

Comment: @nörbörnën проблема в том, что мне такие элементы были не нужны. Нужна была только загрузка данных из массива в компонент, в котором уже есть нужная мне разметка.

Answer (score 1):

Ключ — это специальный строковый атрибут, который нужно указывать при создании списка элементов. [Тут](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) можно почитать подробнее
Ключи помогают React определять, какие элементы были изменены, добавлены или удалены. Их необходимо указывать, чтобы React мог сопоставлять элементы массива с течением времени

Comment: Я в курсе, что такое ключи, но я не понимаю, почему при сборке в listItems оно начинает втирать эту ошибку, ибо сделано все по гайду из документации.